# Javafx - can a loop be paused?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I have never heard of a loop being paused before, but I'm still learning and I'm trying to make a poker game to where each AI makes there choice if one of them raises the bet then the round must continue until everyone has met that bet or folded I'm sort of learning the game as I go. I'm working with a Texas Hold Em style of poker and I want the players to make their choices and then have the game continue after the player has made theirs. If a loop can't be paused and I doubt it can, then what would be the best way to go about doing this?

I basically have a class with a set of rules, the players cards get passed to it along with the community cards, gets analyzed and the best hand is returned.

The AI will be created using the same class that the players hand is created with and a separate class will be created for controlling each AI's hand.

The system is setup so that I can basically add different rule sets for different styles of poker and casino card games.

I'm trying to create my first full blown program while at the same time writing it in a way that will allow it to be easily modified so that you can add or take away elements without having to rewrite everything

Edit: Alright, cool so i read through James_D's post and since the rotation of the game changes each game until a new game is created (Think 6 players sitting around a table one is randomly chosen as the dealer at the start, each game the dealer becomes the person to the left of the current dealer every game until a new game is started and the process is then restarted). So what ill do is load all the players in an ArrayList in the order they are to play according to who the dealer is for that game and set a variable for tracking the players turn, when its the next players turn an action such as call, check, raise, or fold will change the players turn and will notify the next player it is their turn, if this is an AI then they will make their decision upon this notification

Comment: Met the bet, checked, or folded is actually how it goes i believe

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pausing the loop". Do you want to make the UI unresponsive until it's human player's turn again?

Comment: I wouldn't use a loop at all for this, but would make it event-driven. See [this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/message/11172057#11172057) from OTN. I created a Tic-Tac-Toe game (computer vs human) which is linked in there.

Comment: Thanks @James_D that helps quite a bit